# R - Calculating annual incrementals across different categories

Tags: r

I am trying to find out a way how add a column with incremental change from previous year for each category of my data. Example of my data would be this:

```
  Year CommodityCode Country Value
1 2014 123456        UK      10
2 2014 123456        US      15
3 2014 123457        UK      5
4 2014 123457        US      7
5 2015 123456        UK      11
6 2015 123456        US      16
7 2015 123457        UK      10
8 2015 123457        US      10
```

And What I would like to get is something like this:

```
  Year CommodityCode Country Value Change
1 2014 123456        UK      10    NA
2 2014 123456        US      15    NA
3 2014 123457        UK      5     NA
4 2014 123457        US      7     NA
5 2015 123456        UK      11    1
6 2015 123456        US      16    1
7 2015 123457        UK      10    5
8 2015 123457        US      10    3
```

I am running this for a fairly large dataset with 100 countries, million different commodities and across 10 years so was hoping for a code which wouldn't take too long. I am completely new to R but spent quite some time googling this and couldn't find any solution - apologies if this was asked before.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where `dplyr` shines:

```
library("dplyr")

data <- readr::read_delim("Year CommodityCode Country Value
2014 123456 UK 10
2014 123456 US 15
2014 123457 UK 5
2014 123457 US 7
2015 123456 UK 11
2015 123456 US 16
2015 123457 UK 10
2015 123457 US 10", 
delim=" ")

result <- data %>% 
  group_by(Country, CommodityCode) %>% 
  mutate(Change = Value - lag(Value, 1, order_by = Year))
result

Source: local data frame [8 x 5]
Groups: Country, CommodityCode [4]
   Year CommodityCode Country Value Change
  <int>         <int>   <chr> <int>  <int>
1  2014        123456      UK    10     NA
2  2014        123456      US    15     NA
3  2014        123457      UK     5     NA
4  2014        123457      US     7     NA
5  2015        123456      UK    11      1
6  2015        123456      US    16      1
7  2015        123457      UK    10      5
8  2015        123457      US    10      3
```